# Reply to a Facebook page comment as yourself from mobile

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-comments

Trying to like and comment a post from another page admin as myself on Facebook Mobile (Android).  It does not appear to be possible from what I can tell.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using the Android app or the mobile web? If it's the former, your question would be better off at [android.se].

Comment: Is there any way to do this on the mobile web app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a smartphone app.

Comment: Hmm hmmm.... according to [this page](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10104010462807274) it seems it is not possible in the app :/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Facebook app for Android, open app, there is three horizontal lines beside to notification symbol. Click on that. It has the list of all page where you are admin with your own profile. Click the page on which you want comment. Now you are on page. There is three vertical dots beside `Edit Page`, click on that dots. Scroll down to get `**Edit Settings**`, click on *Edit Settings*, now you will see `Post Attribution`, click on that. Its has two options:
***Post as Page Name

Post as Your Name***
Select the second one option and click on save. Now you will be able to Like and Comment on page as your name.

Comment: While this setting is accessible within the Android app, it does not actually have any effect on activity actually performed using the app. It only affects the default behavior of activities performed using the browser platform.